# Firefox trying to download json from grails

Tags: json, firefox, grails

I have a grails controller whose last line is

```
render results as JSON
```

It is being rendered to an iframe. When firefox processes this, it tries to download the json file. Is this normal? The only way I've been able to get around this is to convert it to a string and then handle it on the javascript side.

Answer (score 4):

I have a grails controller in which I wrote something like this and I've got String message. Try this example.

```
String msg = g.message(code: "default.errors.login.fail")
render([error: msg] as JSON)
```

Comment: That seems to work, but now how to do I get the msg out on the javascript side. before I was just using JSON.parse, but that doesn't seem to work anymore with this new way.

Comment: The msg passed to view and you can access it through javascript. Maybe I don't understand your question clearly, but I don't see here any problem.

Comment: I don't do much javascript development so I'm not sure of the syntax to get at the msg part of the JSON.

Comment: can use write the code here, only view part, where you get the msg ?

Comment: var data = JSON.parse(json); This worked when I was just returning it as plain text, but since I added the block you specified above, this does not work.

Comment: Please write in more details. What are you passing from controller currently ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10075/discussion-between-emilan-and-jeff-storey)